# "peeked over the balcony," "peeked out the balcony," or "peeked out of the balcony"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

What's the correct construction? Say, you're inside the house and are peeking to see what's in the balcony?

Example sentence:

> Faking courage, I peeked **over/out/out** of the balcony.

Answer (score 2):

The three examples in your title all mean that you are on the balcony and looking somewhere else from there. I think that what you mean to say is

> Faking courage, I peeked **out** (of the house) **onto** the balcony

or even

> Faking courage, I peeked **into** the balcony

if it's more of an enclosed space and almost like a room.